# How to add custom template tag in wordpress theme?

Tags: theme-development, functions, customization

I am working on a WordPress site, it's an online newspaper site.

The theme I am developing, I want to add custom template functions like `get_footer()` or `get_header()`, so that I can save those HTML and PHP codes like the way `footer.php` stores.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your function in the file function.php and use it later in your theme.

Answer (score 5):

In Wordpress 3.0 you can use

```
get_template_part($slug, $name);
```

This function will include file named "{slug}-{name}.php". The $name is optional, and if it's empty, the function will include file named "{slug}.php".

There is also the traditional PHP-code, but this do not check if the file exsist.

```
include(TEMPLATEPATH . 'template-name.php');
```